# Mocking addProvider(Class<?> klass)

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am trying to get used Mockito.

I have a class

```
@Provider
public class SessionProvider  implements InjectableProvider<Bind, Type>{


   @Override
   public ComponentScope getScope() {
      return ComponentScope.PerRequest;
   }

   @Override
   public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Bind bind, Type parameter) {
      return new SessionInjectable();
   }
}
```

And trying to return null when getInjectable is called.

My use case is like so

```
public void addProvider(Class<?> klass) {
    providers.add(klass);
}

addProvider(SessionProvider.class);
```

How can I successfully mock SessionProvider.class?

Thanks

Edit:

My class is like so:

```
@Path("message")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MessageResource {

   @POST
   @Path("post")
   public String testPostMessage(@Bind Session session, Message message) {
       return "posted";
   }
}
```

Bind annotation is using my provider. But my current framework does not accept instances of SessionProvider. It is utilizing Class instances.

By the way this is a web service. It is called by my client implementation. I would like to test my message with a mocked session. And for each request it is requested a new one. That is the reason the method is accepting Session Class instead of Session Instance.

I really started to feel that there is something wrong but at where?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a mock return `null` :

```
SessionProvider sessionProvider = mock(SessionProvider.class);
assertNull(sessionProvider.getInjectable(ic, bind, parameter));
```

For a unit test, you can test `MessageResource` by invoking `testPostMessage` with mocks :

```
messageResource.testPostMessage(mock(SessionMessage.class), mock(Message.class));
```

or, you could create a mock `SessionProvider` class returning a mock `Session` :

```
@Provider
public class MockSessionProvider  implements InjectableProvider<Bind, Type>{
    public Injectable getInjectable(ComponentContext ic, Bind bind, Type parameter) {
      return mock(Session.class);
    }
}
```

and then register it on the framework :

```
addProvider(MockSessionProvider.class);
```

Comment: It seems it is impossible to create new mock instance with mockito. But your second suggestion can work. That is why I accepted. Thanks